# Change theme dialog in android

Tags: android, android-layout

This is possible to change theme my dialog in code? This is my dialog:

```
            Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActionBarMain.this);
            dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

            dialog.setContentView(R.layout.log_in_dialog_view);
            dialog.show();
```

Comment: can you please describe further?

Comment: i am using in my app Theme.Holo but I want to my dialog use Theme.Black. This is possible to do?

Comment: see links http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#CustomDialog and http://www.thiyagaraaj.com/articles/android-articles/customdialogboxpopupusinglayoutinandroid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dialog has a secondary constructor that takes a Theme:

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog(android.content.Context, int)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Dialog.html#Dialog%28android.content.Context,%20int%29)

try:

```
 Dialog dialog = new Dialog(ActionBarMain.this, android.R.style.Theme_Black);
```